# how to prove that the following ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2(x-1))$ are not prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I want to prove that the ideals $\frac{(x^2)}{(x^2(x-1))}, \frac{(x(x-1))}{(x^2(x-1))},\frac{(x^2(x-1))}{(x^2(x-1))}=(0)$ are not prime in the ring $R=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2(x-1))$. So it is enough to show that for each ideal $I$ we have $R/I \simeq L$ where $L$ is not a domain.
My tries so far:

$\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2(x-1))}{(0)}\simeq \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2(x-1))\simeq \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2) \times \mathbb{Q}$ not a domain

$\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2(x-1))}{(x^2)/(x^2(x-1))}\simeq \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2)$ which is a ring of dual numbers so it is not a domain (?)

$\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2(x-1))}{(x(x-1))/(x^2(x-1))}\simeq \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x(x-1))\simeq \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} $ which is not a domain.

Can someone help me  and check if my tries are correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks good to me. To see that $\mathbb{Q}[X]/\langle X^{2} \rangle$ is not a domain, note that its nilradical is nontrivial (justify this to yourself, if it is not immediately clear!).

Comment: Your try is correct, by you missed some parts of the ideals when wrote the quotient rings for the second and third cases.

Comment: The second and third isomorphisms seem to be incorrect, and in fact to show what you want can be done easier (imo) as follows: write $\;I=\langle x^2(x-1)\rangle\;$ , then $$x^2+I\,,\,(x-1)+I\notin I\;,\;\;\text{yet}\;\;(x^2+I)((x-1)+I)\in I\ldots$$